# Search with regex if name exist in database

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm using a regex to check if a name already exist in the database. I'm using mongo filters.

I'm using like this:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(title) == false)
{
   List<FilterDefinition<object>> MyFilters = new List<FilterDefinition<object>>();

   MyFilters.Add(Builders<object>.Filter.Eq(x => x.object.id, objectDefinitionId));
   MyFilters.Add(Builders<object>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Status, ObjectItemStatus.Accepted));
   MyFilters.Add(Builders<object>.Filter.Regex(x => x.Title, new BsonRegularExpression(String.Format(@"^\s*{0}\s*$", title.Trim().ToLower().EscapeRegExCharacters()), "i")));               
}

Int64 MyCount = await m_TenantMongoClient.MongoDbDatabase.GetCollection<object>("collection")
                .CountDocumentsAsync(Builders<object>.Filter.And(MyFilters));

MyResult = MyCount > 0 ? true : false;
```

The problem is that if I have in database a name for example: "abc" and if I want to add another item with the name "abc|something", this regex will find the name, and it return that I already have the name in the database. Somehow if I add a `|` character in the new name, this regex will check only the first part of the name, which is in front of the `|` character, and since I already have it in the db the "abc" name, it will return that the name "abc|something" already exist.

Comment: It does not sound 100% clear. First, why do you need a possessive quantifier? Use simple `@"^\s*{0}\s*$"`. Next, what is your input? If your "title" is `abc|something` and you pass `^\s*abc\s*$` regex to match it, the outcome will be False, there is no way it could match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew-I've tried the regex that you suggested - @"^\s*{0}\s*$" - but this way it also detects that I already have that name in the database. So what I need is to check if a name already exists in database. My regex it works fine, but in one case is not ok. For example if I have already "abc" in db and I want to insert a new object "abc|xxx" it returns that I already have that object with that name

Comment: That does not make sense. Regex itself does not check your DB contents, you need to use some method or function to do so. And you are likely to need a simel equality comparison for this, not a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I am not using the regex alone. I updated the question with the function that I'm using to check whatever the name exists or not

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you expecting to consider `|` as not part of a regex? Want to  escape it?

Comment: @Gibbs - I want to be able to add both names in database. "abc" and also "abc|xxx"

Comment: What is that `abc`? A field or a value? I guess its a value

Comment: @Gibbs -  "abc" it's the value that already exists in the database, the field name is "Title", as it is on my query that I copy pasted in the question. And I also need to insert "abc|xxx", but my query finds the "abc" entry, so I can not insert.

Comment: Didn't that resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Gibbs - "abc" it's the value that already exists in the database, the field name is "Title", as it is on my query that I copy pasted in the question. And I also need to insert "abc|xxx", but my query finds the "abc" entry, so I can not insert

It is the perfect use case of `unique index`. Create an index on the field `Title` it will automatically prevent you from inserting a duplicate value on that field.

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/)

Comment: This is not the right solution. The main problem is, that the I character is 'seen' by the regex as an or. So if I want to add a new object with the name "abc|xxx", then the regex will  check " abc" or "xxx"... and this why I can't insert the name "abc|xxx". But I want to insert a name which contains a I character. But anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Try escaping the pipe symbol